# `\startalign` and `\startcases` are not compatible

Tags: context, cases, alignment

In ConTeXt, it seems that `\startalign` and `\startcases` are not compatible.
If so, what should I do when I want to align an equation containing a case-statement and a following equation?

```
\starttext

\placeformula
\startformula
\startalign % < -- Causes compilation error
\NC f(x) \NC
=\startcases
\NC 1, \MC x >0 \NR
\NC 0,\MC x \leq 0 \NR
\stopcases
\NC g(x) \NC =x^2 +2x +1
\stopalign % < -- Causes compilation error
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each line of a multi-line math align environment must be of the form:

```
\NC .... \NC .... \NR
```

So, you have to close the first line with `\NR` after the `case` environment:

```
\starttext
\startformula \startalign
  \NC f(x) \NC =  \startcases
                      \NC 1,  \MC x >  0 \NR
                      \NC 0,  \MC x >= 0 \NR
                  \stopcases  \NR
  \NC g(x) \NC = x^2 +2x +1   \NR
\stopalign \stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @TeXnician Totally

Comment: Oh, the first `=0` in my question is superfluous. Since the text is invented, I overlooked that. Shall I edit it away for future reader?

Comment: @DG' I changed the language a little bit. Hope that you don't mind.

Comment: @Aditya On the contrary, I appreciate it

Comment: @TeXnician: sorry I misread your comment